# What is a good algorithm, and framework, to calculate centres of gravity or mass (cog)?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, shape-analysis

I'd like to take an photograph, subdivide it into a tesselation, either of squares, or (ideally), hexagons, and then find the centre of gravity (or, if you prefer, centre of mass) of each cell of the tesselation.

The output, for any image, would be a matrix of points. For the attached diagram, something like this (in polar coordinates - $(r,\theta)$ ):

```
(5,5Π/4) (0,0) (1,7Π/4) (1,5Π/4)
(5,3Π/4) (0,0) (5,Π/2) 
(0.0) (0,0) (0.0) (0,0)
```

I have asked this question in 'Computer Graphics', but not had any replies, so I thought it might fit better with the expertise here in terms of image processing.

I've attached an image showing what I mean. The black circles are the centres of gravity of each cell - in clear, or monochrome, cells it is in the centre of the cell. In those with a green splodge, the cog is pulled towards the splodge.

[image: Hexagonal tesselation. The black circles are the centres of gravity of each cell - in clear, or monochrome, cells it is in the centre of the cell. In those with a green splodge, the cog is pulled towards the splodge]

My question, to put it simply, what is the best method to use to calculate the cog, in this tessellation... For squares, it'd be easy to calculate the weighted mean for each row, but that would be too rough an approximation. What's a good way to iterate either a general tessellation (ideal), or an hexagonal one?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? As written, it looks like you want to be provided with a working solution, and that is off-topic here. If you are working on a solution and have a specific question related to image processing, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a working solution - obviously, if there is one, I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel, but I've looked, and not found what I need. The division of the space in an hexagonal tessellation is part of what I'm working on in my solution - squares are too coarse, and circles don't tessellate.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, though, I've, as you suggest, added a specific question, and given some idea of my working so far.

Comment: Thanks! The question is clear now, at least to me. I edited it a little bit to pull the image description out of the image text.

Comment: @PeterBrooks You asked [this exact question on Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24953/what-is-a-good-algorithm-and-framework-to-calculate-centres-of-gravity-or-mass). An answer has been provided there and you seem satisfied with it. Please consider deleting this one here as [Cross-posting is not appreciated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)  on SE sites, and shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: I am closing this question since, you x-posted it with CS S.E., as well as copy pasted the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it is a x-post of: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/24953/what-is-a-good-algorithm-and-framework-to-calculate-centres-of-gravity-or-mass